# Struct recebendo a mesma struct como atributo

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Olá, como posso ter uma struct "recursiva"? Uma struct que recebe ela mesma como um dos atributos.

```
typedef struct {
    int value;

    NODE[50];
} NODE;
```

Nesse caso, a ideia é que cada Node tenha um vetor com 50 nodes filhos. Como posso fazer? Obrigado

Comment: Você tem de usar um ponteiro cujo tipo é a estrutura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma que está tentando não vai conseguir porque está tentando declarar uma *estrutura* onde cada *nó* terá *50 nós* e cada um desses *nós* terá outros *50 nós* e cada um desses *nós*.. Sendo assim, acho que deve usar apenas um ponteiro ao invés de um vetor.

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
    NODE *filho;
} NODE;
```

Porém acredito que você precise controlar os *50 nós* filhos específicos de cada *nó*, e aí está o problema. Você poderia *incrementar* sua *struct* pra manter uma lista de itens, mas em cada um ter o *pai* e a *quantidade* que cada um tem de filhos, controlando isso na hora de adicionar um novo item:

```
typedef struct {
    int indice; //por exemplo a posição deste item (1, 2, 3...) 
    int indice_pai; //a quem este elemento está referenciado
    int qtd_filhos; //inicializaria em 0 e receberia +1 a cada novo filho - serve para controlar os 50 máximos

    int value;
    NODE *filho;
} NODE;
```

Realmente fica bem mais complexo de controlar se precisar disso, mas acredito ser uma solução possível!!